# find the three most sold products every day php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to find the three most sold products every day and
show them together with number of sales.

However if there are more than one product sharing the same
number of sales I just want to tell how many products got this
ranking.

I have two tables

```
Products:
+-----+---------+
| Pid | Product |
+-----+---------+
|  1  | Moon    |
|  2  | Sun     |
|  3  | Venus   |
|  4  | Mars    |
+-----+---------+

SalesRows:
+-----+---------+------------+
| Pid | No_sold | Sales_date |
+-----+---------+------------+
|  1  |    1    | 2013-01-01 |
|  2  |    5    | 2013-01-01 |
|  3  |    2    | 2013-01-01 |
|  2  |    2    | 2013-01-01 |
+-----+---------+------------+
```

Should give:

```
+------+--------------+-------+
| Rank | Product      | Sales |
+------+--------------+-------+
|  1   | Sun          |   7   |
|  2   | Venus        |   2   |
|  3   | Moon         |   1   |
+------+--------------+-------+
```

However this sales data:

```
SalesRows:
+-----+---------+------------+
| Pid | No_sold | Sales_date |
+-----+---------+------------+
|  1  |    1    | 2013-01-01 |
|  2  |    5    | 2013-01-01 |
|  3  |    2    | 2013-01-01 |
|  2  |    2    | 2013-01-01 |
|  4  |    1    | 2013-01-01 |
+-----+---------+------------+
```

Should give:

```
+------+--------------+-------+
| Rank | Product      | Sales |
+------+--------------+-------+
|  1   | Sun          |   7   |
|  2   | Venus        |   2   |
|  3   | *2 products* |   1   |
+------+--------------+-------+
```

Any suggestions how to solve this last part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query may help you.

```
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 rownum, 
       t.* 
  FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, 
       (select case when indicator = 1 then Product
else concat( indicator, ' Products') end as Product, sales from (Select *, count(sales) as indicator from (SELECT Product,SUM(No_sold) AS sales FROM SalesRows
JOIN Products ON Products.Pid = SalesRows.Pid
WHERE Sales_date = curdate()
GROUP BY SalesRows.Pid ) a group by sales Order by sales desc) a) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT Product,SUM(No_sold) AS sales FROM SalesRows 
LEFT JOIN Products ON Products.Pid = SalesRows.Pid
WHERE Sales_date = '".$today."'
GROUP BY Pid
```

Comment: Would be better if you actually explained the SQL statement rather than just spoonfeeding it.

Comment: This does not sort by rank, and also does not solve the question how to present when two or more products get the same ranking